# Expected value calculation for $S_t=S_0+\mu t+ \sigma W_t$

Tags: statistics

I am given the following and there's a small bit that I don't know how to deal with.

> Price of a stock is given by $S_t=S_0+ \mu t+ \sigma W_t$.  $W_t$ is a Brownian motion. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[S_t-S_0]$, $Var[S_t-S_0]$, $\mathbb{E}[S_T-S_t$, and $Cov(S_t-S_0,S_T-S_t)$ for $t \in[0,T]$.

My question

> $\mathbb{E}[S_t-S_0]=\mathbb{E}[\mu t + \sigma dW_t]=\mu \mathbb{E}[t]+\sigma \cdot 0=\mu \mathbb{E}[t]$ question is, if I am right up to here...how to deal with $\mathbb{E}[t]$. All I know about $t$ is that it's a time variable. I don't know how it's distributed, what it's mean or variance is or...it's just a variable. Perhaps I can say continuous is all I know.

How do I find $\mathbb{E}[t]$?

It would be great if someone can answer...thanks so much

Comment: In general, if t is a (time) variable with domain [a,b] (could be infinite limits), and $X_t$ is a stochastic process with pdf $f_{X_t}(x)$, then the expectation is found by $E[X_t]=\int_a^b xf_{X_t}(x)dx$. In your case $X_t=t$ and you can apply this formula. Be a tad careful: could it be that $X_t=t$ is a random variable.

Comment: Do you mean $\text{Cov}[S_t-S_0,S_T-S_t]$?

Comment: Sorry, yeah that was a typo, fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by Brownian motion, you mean a standard BM. Then
$$X(t) = \mu t+ \sigma B(t)$$
is a Brownian motion with drift $\mu$ and variance parameter $\sigma^2$. 
With Brownian motions, $X(t+s)-X(s)\sim N(\mu t, \sigma^2 t)$, then
$$E[X(t+0)-X(0)] = \mu t.$$ 
This also gives that 
$$\text{Var}[X(t)-X(0)] = \sigma^2 t.$$

Comment: I see, thanks for answering; So to be clear, the variable is $x$ and no anything else...so, time variable $t$ in this case, for expectation is constant? And the same applies when I calculated variance too, yes?